# Why use element[0] instead of element when creating AngularJS directive with d3?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

It seems that you have to use `element[0]` when creating a directive with D3, for example, like below:

```
app.directive('firstTry', function () {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var sampleSVG = d3.select(element[0])
        ...
```

So, why `element[0]` but not `element`? The name `element` suggests that it is a single object rather than an array, but apparently that's not the case. Another question: what else does this `element` have?

BTW, any official references about this matter would greatly help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `console.dir(element)` should already give you more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Directives that want to modify the DOM typically use the `link` option. `link` takes a function with the following signature, `function link(scope, element, attrs) { ... }` where:
>
> - `scope` is an Angular scope object.
> - `element` is the jqLite-wrapped element that this directive matches.
> - `attrs` is a hash object with key-value pairs of normalized attribute names and their corresponding attribute values.

you can find it in documentation [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) . So to key htmlElement entity - get first member of collection